# Showing data in array list with edit text in android

Tags: java, xml

i'm working on a app in which i can send data with edit text and show in array list but don't know how i can do that.In array list the data i want to show is title and the description of the data with the help of edit text.

Comment: please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: u understand what i want to say